# Loop to every row in a Worksheet, copy in new Workbook and SaveAs

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a worksheet containing employee data in the rows(called Master). From A1:X1 is the header. The data I need is in range A2:X.
There is another workbook in the same directory that will be sent to the employees for a survey(called survey).

I need to write VBA code that copies the Data in A2:X2, opens the survey workbook and pastes it into A1:X1. Then it should save it as a new workbook. The name of the new file should be the value in cell X1. Then it should go on to the next row A3:X3 and repeat everything and so on. So it should loop through every row (except the header) of the master file.

My code works manually for each row. But since the number of rows is about 2 to 300 and variable I need a loop.

My code to copy the first two rows and SaveAs.

```vb
Sub copy_data()
    Dim wbstart, wbtarget As Workbook
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim cell As Range
    strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
    Set wbstart = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wbtarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Tool\survey.xlsx")
    wbstart.Sheets("master").Range("A2:X2").Copy Destination:=wbtarget.Sheets("1").Range("A2:X2")
    wbtarget.SaveAs Filename:=strPath & "\" & Range("X2")
    wbstart.Sheets("master").Range("A3:X3").Copy Destination:=wbtarget.Sheets("1").Range("A2:X2")
    wbtarget.SaveAs Filename:=strPath & "\" & Range("X2")
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "finished"
   
End Sub
```

Since both files remain in the same directory, but the directory will be moved when finished, there has to be some other way to specify wbtarget.

Comment: `For i = 2 to wbstart.Sheets("master").Cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row`

Comment: where exactly should I add this line?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. I added a `With` to make things easier, and changed the syntax of your ranges to make it easier to work with a variable.

```
Sub copy_data()
    Dim wbstart As Workbook, wbtarget As Workbook 'You need As for each one, otherwise they are variants
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
    Set wbstart = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wbtarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Tool\survey.xlsx")
    With wbstart.Sheets("Master")
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 24)).Copy Destination:=wbtarget.Sheets("1").Range(wbtarget.Sheets("1").Cells(i, 1), wbtarget.Sheets("1").Cells(i, 24))
            wbtarget.SaveAs Filename:=strPath & "\" & .Cells(i, 24).Value
        Next i
    End With
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "finished"
   
End Sub
```